# MySQL Array to string conversion error

Tags: php, mysql

This is the code in question

```
<?php
include ("Connections/localhost.php");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM questions LEFT OUTER JOIN answers ON questions.quest_id = answers.ans_question WHERE answers.ans_question IS null;");
$lessons= mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
?>
```

When I echo $lessons I get:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\gwishin\dashboard.php on line 21
```

I know things have changed since the last time I touched PHP/MySQL but I thought this was correct or is every query now an array even though I should only get one answer back?

Comment: `$lesson[] = mysql_fetch_assoc(result);` the function returns `array` so you need that.

Answer (score 0):

Because $lessons is an array. Try

```
echo $lessons['total'];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the right way to use `mysql_fetch_assoc` you can take a look [Here](https://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc)

```
while ($lessons = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["first_col_name_in_db"];
    echo $row["sec_col_name_in_db"];
    echo $row["third_col_name_in_db"];
}
```

Please read this

**Warning**

About Mysql

This extension is deprecated as of `PHP 5.5.0`, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the `MySQLi` or `PDO_MySQL` extension should be used. See also `MySQL`: choosing an `API` guide and related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function include:
`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`
`PDOStatement::fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`

Answer (score 0):

[mysql_fetch_assoc](https://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc) returns associative array of strings that corresponds to the fetched row, or FALSE if there are no more rows.

Also, `This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0`

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you're using `mysql_fetch_assoc($result);` on an invalid `$result`.
Test whether `$result` is valid (`!= FALSE`) before iterating on `mysql_fetch_assoc`.